# dump odex from memory gdb

Tags: android, gdb

after searching alot i am unable to dump odex file of running process in android

i used

> dumpsys meminfo

to get process id

used

> gdb -pid xxx

to dump and then

> gcore

to save dump of core

i am looking for a other way from terminal command to dump odex of process id which can work reliably on android 6 as well as above will work on android jelly bean n below

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameGuardian](http://gameguardian.net/download) for this. Need root.

Memory editor tab - menu - memory dump - input 0-0 as range and folder - press ok - wait for toast `Dump end`.
Go to selected folder - open maps file - search needed odex in regions - remember start address of region - open GameGuardian - menu - memory dump - input remembered address in both field as range - press ok - wait for toast `Dump end`.
Now you have in your folder `.bin` file with dumped odex file.

Here some video examples how to do this:

- [How to dump odex file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/251-how-to-dump-odex-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)